# How to get a query string variable in php

Tags: php

I have a php for loop and inside the php for loop there is a button element inside a td tag. I am passing button Id from one page to another using query String.

page 1:

```
 $id = $data['no'];
<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-small"><a href="votingPoll.php?'.$str.'">SUBMIT</a></button></td>
```

To get the value of the button id i have this code in page 2:

```
$id = $_GET['str'];
```

but for some reason it's giving me a error of undefined variable 'str' on page 2.

Comment: In page 1 add `var_dump($str);` and update your question with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-small"><a href="votingPoll.php?id='.$id .'">SUBMIT</a></button></td>
```

on yourpage.php or whichever file you would like to recieve the data, access it with `$_GET['id']`

Comment: Thank you, Can you all explain how to send multiple values in query string

Comment: multiple id's? or different data types?

Comment: multiple id's i think so.